# Dynamically switch between text field and label

Tags: vaadin

I have a data table whose data source is a container having a pojo class. The pojo class has a button `edit`. I want to make a label change to text box when `edit` is clicked by user. I have tried a bunch of ways, but none seem to work. I have created a class `Editable` where I can switch but how do I reload the table's components from the pojo class?

Comment: The POJO has a Button..?? What version of Vaadin are you using?

Comment: Try to share what you have attempted so far, so others will have an easier time helping you out.